# Adding row to a dataframe

Tags: r, rows

I have a df like this:

```
x <- data.frame("Year" = c(1945,1945,1946,1946,1947,1947), "Age" = c(1,2,1,2,1,2), "Value" = c(4,5,4,5,4,6))
```

I would like to add new rows based on some conditions:
For example, I want to add the second row that has the same "YEAR" and "AGE," as the first row, but the Value is the value of the first row minis 1.

I want my result like this:

```
x <- data.frame("Year" = c(1945, 1945,1945,1945,1946,1946,1946,1946,1947,1947,1947,1947), "Age" = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), "Value" = c(4,3,5,4,4,3,5,4,4,3,5,4))
```

Thank you for helping a beginner.

Comment: I don't quite understand your conditions - can you clarify? For example, why is `5` in row 3 in your desired output?

Comment: You can try this:`value <- data.frame(x$Year, x$Value-1, x$Age)` then `colnames(value) <- c("Year", "Value", "Age")` and finally `p <- full_join(x, value, by = c("Year", "Value", "Age"))`. `value` creates a dataframe with the values you want. `colnames` changes the column names to match the original. and `full_join` merges the two dataframes by their column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base`, you can repeat each row twice and add recycled `0:-1` to `Value`.

```
within(x[rep(1:nrow(x), each = 2), ], Value <- Value + 0:-1)
```

---

Its `tidyverse` version is

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>%
  uncount(2) %>% 
  mutate(Value = Value + 0:-1)
```

---

Both of them give the following. The output has been ordered well, so you don't need to use `order()` or `arrange()`.

```
   Year Age Value
1  1945   1     4
2  1945   1     3
3  1945   2     5
4  1945   2     4
5  1946   1     4
6  1946   1     3
7  1946   2     5
8  1946   2     4
9  1947   1     4
10 1947   1     3
11 1947   2     6
12 1947   2     5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
#original df
x <- data.frame("Year" = c(1945,1945,1946,1946,1947,1947), "Age" = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),"Value" = c(4,5,4,5,4,6))

#replicate df with value minus 1
y <- data.frame(x[,c("Year", "Age")], Value = x[,"Value"] -1)

#combine
z <- rbind(x,y)
```

```
z[order(z$Year, z$Age),]

   Year Age Value
1  1945   1     4
7  1945   1     3
2  1945   2     5
8  1945   2     4
3  1946   1     4
9  1946   1     3
4  1946   2     5
10 1946   2     4
5  1947   1     4
11 1947   1     3
6  1947   2     6
12 1947   2     5
```

The code above could be shortened of course, for instance to this when updating your dataframe x directly.

```
x <- rbind(x, data.frame(x[,c("Year", "Age")], Value = x[,"Value"] -1))
```

As pointed out in the comment below, the code could be further shortened (and made more readable) by using `transform()` or `within()`.

```
x <- rbind(x, transform(x, Value = Value - 1))
x <- rbind(x, within(x, Value <- Value - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% inner_join(x %>% select(1)) %>% group_by(Year, Age) %>% 
mutate(Value = case_when(row_number() == 2 ~ Value - 1, TRUE ~ Value))
Joining, by = "Year"
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Year, Age [6]
    Year   Age Value
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1945     1     4
 2  1945     1     3
 3  1945     2     5
 4  1945     2     4
 5  1946     1     4
 6  1946     1     3
 7  1946     2     5
 8  1946     2     4
 9  1947     1     4
10  1947     1     3
11  1947     2     6
12  1947     2     5
```

Data used:

```
x
  Year Age Value
1 1945   1     4
2 1945   2     5
3 1946   1     4
4 1946   2     5
5 1947   1     4
6 1947   2     6
```